# Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object

Tags: javascript, bots, telegram

I want to create button in my telegram bot by javascript and I working in script google.

But it didn't fetch.

My code:

```
function a() {
  const opts = {
    reply_to_message_id: '690534265',
    reply_markup: {
      resize_keyboard: true,
      one_time_keyboard: true,
      keyboard: [ ['test'], ['test1'] ]
    }
  };

  MainKeyBoard(opts, 'afs', '690534265');
}


function MainKeyBoard(tasti, toxt, chid) {
  var url = link + '/sendMessage?parse_mode=Markdown' +
    '&chat_id=' + chid +
    '&text=' + toxt +
    '&reply_markup=' + tasti;
  var respose = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```

This is my error:

```
   Request failed for https://api.telegram.org/bot745193421:<token>/sendMessage?parse_mode=Markdown&chat_id=690534265&text=afs&reply_markup=[object%20Object] returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

I tried to add JSON.parse but error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: o
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `opts` is an object when you are trying to concatenate it will use the `toString()` method which will just return `[object Object]` that you can see in the request.

In order to solve this issue serialize your object using `JSON.stringify` in your `MainKeyboard` function.

```
function MainKeyBoard(tasti, toxt, chid) {
  var url = link + '/sendMessage?parse_mode=Markdown&chat_id=' + chid +
    '&text=' + toxt + '&reply_markup=' + JSON.stringify(tasti);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}
```